Why does windows set network IPv4 configurations on a per-adapter basis and not per-network? Can this be changed?
As far as I can tell, my installation of windows 10 sets this tab of information on a per-adapter basis - meaning that if I switch from my home network to my hotspot, for example, it keeps my manually assigned IP and reports that there's no internet.
Is there a solution to this? Is this behaving as intended? Seems like unintended behavior.

Is this behaving as intended? yes. Most people use DHCP (Obtain an IP address automatically) thereby allowing "the network" (DHCP server) to configure the correct settings.

So the concepts you are asking about pre-date wifi and the idea that systems roam from network to network on an adhoc basis. Note that its not just windows, I don't know of any PC OS that handles it differently. if you have a static IP for an interface, it is global. I'm pretty sure most mobile OSes do the same if you do configure statically. I recommend instead creating a DHCP reservation on your network for the device, and then set it to use DHCP. it will allow you to connect to networks adhoc, but always give you the 192.168.0.42 address when connected to your home network.

“Is there a solution to this?” - Is there a solution to what exactly? You can either use the same adapter always. Configure all adapters once so they are always configured. You can configure the default DNS provider instead, by default that’s typically the router, that way by default it’s always correct. Your question needs to be clarified.

There is no standard/reliable way for your system to detect which network you are on. Even on Wi-Fi, the same SSID is no guarantee that the same IP settings should be used. Some OSes try to use shaky heuristics to try to "fingerprint" a network based on things like what subnet it's using and what the default gateway's MAC address is, but that's not reliable enough to use as a basis for automatically changing your NIC's IP config.
So you can either leave your NICs set to be auto-configured via DHCP or SLAAC, or you can take responsibility for manually switching them to the right config for the network you're connecting them to.

I'm not sure if that really answers much – several existing systems do it purely based on SSID (iOS, Android, Linux, I think macOS as well) and it works well enough.

Yes, this is intended behavior.  It is set on a per adapter basis.  The simple reason is that a computer can have more than one network adapter on the same network.  Therefore, each network adapter has to be addressed individually and uniquely.
You can resolve this by using DHCP, which will request an IP from the DHCP server (your router or hotspot) and be assigned an IP automatically.  This is the option you see that says, "Obtain an IP address automatically."  If you want to make sure the assigned IP stays constant. (generally, not needed for most people), these devices almost certainly will have a feature called DHCP reservation, which will always assign the same IP to the same adapter based on it's MAC address.
